# Laravel redirect to post method

Tags: rest, post, laravel, routes, laravel-4

To stay basic I would like to create a bookmark app

I have a simple bookmarklet

```
javascript:location.href='http://zas.dev/add?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)
```

I created a rest controller

```
<?php

use zas\Repositories\DbLinkRepository;

class LinksController extends BaseController {

protected $link;

function __construct(DbLinkRepository $link) {

        $this->link=$link;
        // ...
        //$this->beforeFilter('auth.basic', array('except' => array('index', 'show', 'store')));
        // ...
}


public function index()
{
    //return Redirect::to('home');
}
public function create()
{

}
public function store()
{
    return 'hello';
    //$this->link->addLink(Input::get('url'));
    //return Redirect::to(Input::get('url'));
}
public function show($id)
{
    //$url = $this->link->getUrl($id);
    //return Redirect::to($url);
}
public function edit($id)
{

}
public function update($id){

}
public function destroy($id){

}
}
```

in the routes.php, I created a ressource

```
Route::resource('links','LinksController');
```

and as I want to redirect /add to the store method I added

```
Route::get('/add',function(){
    return Redirect::action('LinksController@store');
});
```

but it never display the hello message, in place it redirects me to

http://zas.dev/links

I also tried with

```
return Redirect::route('links.store');
```

without much success

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I now get what you are trying to do. This will work:

```
Route::get('add', 'LinksController@store');
```

Remove:

```
Route::resource('links','LinksController');
```

and remove:

```
Route::get('/add',function(){
   return Redirect::action('LinksController@store');
});
```

Sorry it took so long!

Comment: thanks Sidney, but it doesn't really answer the question, maybe I miss something . The request from the bookmarklet is a GET and not a POST, I don't see in your code what can handle this

Comment: From what are you sending? Framework (BackboneJS, EmberJS) or regular AJAX call?

Comment: from the bookmarklet at the beginning of my question so it's really basic
but my question is more : why the redirect to the store method doesn't work

Comment: PS: you might try to put the route like this: Route::get('add', 'LinksController@store'); That works for me, tried it on my own resource controller!

Comment: wow, as simple as this.
as you said earlier the redirect doesn't work for POST with restful controller, I don't really understand why  but your solution is exactly what I need. 
Create an answer so I can vote for it

Comment: I allready did, it's this answer only with a RESTful tutorial! ;)

Comment: I created a question and answered my own question on creating an API for SPA applications like BackboneJS. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448159/how-do-i-create-a-restful-api-in-laravel-to-use-in-my-backbonejs-app

Comment: What you should keep in mind is that everybody can post to that url, it is totally public unless you protect it with OAuth or some other authentication layer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that once you `Redirect::`, you loose all the `Input` values, so you should manually give them to your controller when you do the redirect, like so :

```
Redirect::route('links.store', ["url" => Input::get("url")]);
```

Finally add an `$url` parameter to your `store` method to receive the value we give it in the previous method, like this :

```
public function store($url) {
    $this->link->addLink($url);
    return Redirect::to($url);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip but for the moment that didn't work even without the Input values