# information about route resource in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, laravel-4

I'm new in Laravel 4 development, can't find enough information about `resource` method in `Route` class

```
Route::resource();
```

How to use it?

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 1):

It's a great way to setup API's. It implements RESTful in a clever way. The recourse controller route can catch a request and maps it to a specific method in the controller based on the RESTful state.

routes.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/

// Route group for API versioning
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function() {
    Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
});
```

For example:

```
POST = store() (Create a new entry)
DELETE = destroy($id) (Delete an entry)
GET = index() (Get all entries)
GET = show($id) (Get one entry)
PUT = update($id) (Update an entry)
```

A practical example:
[How do I create a RESTful API in Laravel to use in my BackboneJS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448159/how-do-i-create-a-restful-api-in-laravel-to-use-in-my-backbonejs-app)