# Laravel Undefined Offset: 1 - cause by routing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I get the error when trying to make a post call to `/api/subject/search`

I assume it's a simple syntax error I'm missing

I have my api routes defined below

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function()
{
    Route::post('resource/search', 'ResourceController');
    Route::resource('resource', 'ResourceController');


    Route::post('subject/search', 'SubjectController');
    Route::resource('subject', 'SubjectController');

    Route::resource('user', 'UserController');

    Route::controller('/session', 'SessionController');
    Route::post('/login', array('as' => 'session', 'uses' => 'SessionController@Store'));
});
```

And my controller is mostly empty

```
class SubjectController extends \BaseController 
{
    public function search()
    {
        $subjects = [];
        if((int)Input::get('grade_id') < 13 && (int)Input::get('grade_id') > 8)
            $subjects = Subject::where('name', 'like', '%HS%')->get();
        else
            $subjects = Subject::where('name', 'not like', '%HS%')->get();

        return Response::json([
            'success' => true,
            'subjects' => $subjects->toArray()
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
            //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
            //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
            //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
            //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
            //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
            //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
            //
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show us the *full* error message.

Comment: Is your `search()` method being called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify the method.

try

```
Route::post('subject/search', 'SubjectController@search');
```

See the named route example:
[Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes)

Comment: So, Laravel explodes `'SubjectController@search'`, and tries getting `search` using something like `$arr[1]`, hence the undefined offset of `1`? You should explain your answer a little more thoroughly; the solution is not very helpful without knowing why it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I think **search** is not resolved by the controller to load the `search()` method. You are also sending a POST for search functionality and I guess it's better to do a GET request since POST and PUT are for storing data.

**Conventions**
When creating API's it's a good thing to stick to naming conventions and patterns.

- http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api

**Solution**
Your route could be simpler like this: `api.yourdomain.com/api/subject?search=term1,term2`. Doing this with a GET query makes it going to the `index()` method. There you can check the `GET` params and do your search stuff and return.

Check this for the cleanest and truely RESTful way to make an API in Laravel:

- [How do I create a RESTful API in Laravel to use in my BackboneJS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448159/how-do-i-create-a-restful-api-in-laravel-to-use-in-my-backbonejs-app)

Answer (score 0):

I got same error when accessing object at index of an empty array in view blade php file.