# REST - Laravel redirect POST with body to other route

Tags: php, rest, api, laravel-5

I'm currently re-writing an API with multiple endpoints. However, for legacy purposes it's required that there is a single endpoint which can be used to access all other endpoints. Which endpoint we should redirect to is based upon a custom `action` header send along with the request.

Example:

Input: Header -> Action A
Output: Redirect to route '/some/url' 'ControllerA@someAction'

Input: Header -> Action B
Output: Redirect to route '/some/other/url' 'ControllerB@someOtherAction'

Normally, I could use the redirect() method but then I lose the body of the POST method. All the endpoints I declared are POST methods.

Basically, the question is how can I properly redirect a POST to another route?

Also note I can't use:

```
App::call('App\Http\Controllers\PlanningController@addOrUpdate', ['request' => $request]);
```

Since my method uses a custom Request class to handle the validation. I get an exception telling the argument should be the type of my custom class and `Illuminate\Http\Request` is given.

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444381/laravel-redirect-to-post-method

Comment: @web-nomad redirect doesn't work. The redirect action changes it to a GET request which results in losing the body of the POST request and it throws a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

Comment: wait, does the legacy system clients do send some post request with header action A then the legacy system server send a redirect response or just pass the processing to some another route? since as far as i know redirects only for get methods. or perhaps it redirects with 307 code, [just as explained in this QA](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect).

Comment: @BagusTesa The legacy system has no actual routes, there is just a big if/else statement checking if Action A then run method A

Comment: so, does it actually involve **url changes** that can be perceived from the clients? or it just re-send the request to another system?

Comment: Nope, only one endpoint. There is no actual URL manipulation in the legacy system.

Comment: hmm, i could only think using [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#terminable-middleware) since the processing done in the same system..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually found the answer to my problem. I've created a middleware which will re-create the request based upon the value found in the header.

Here's the handle function of the middleware (only tested on Laravel 5.2):

```
use Request;
use Route;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

...

public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    // Get the header value
    $action = $request->header('action');

    // Find the route by the action name
    $route = Actions::getRouteByName(action); // This returns some route, i.e.: 'api/v1/some/url'

    // Perform the action
    $request = Request::create(route, 'POST', ['body' => $request->getContent()]);
    $response = Route::dispatch($request);

    return new Response($response->getContent(), $response->status(), ['Content-Type' => 'text/xml']); // the last param can be any headers you like
}
```

Please note that this might conflict on your project with other middleware. I've disabled other middleware and created a special routegroup for this. Since we're redirecting the call manually to another route the middleware on that route is called anyway. However, you can also implement this code inside a controller function then there are no conflicting middleware problems!